# Notation to describe that a value is equivalent to at least one component of a vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

Suppose I have the vector $X=<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1>$.  This notation should mean that this is a vector whose respective components are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 1, in that same order.  Suppose I want to show that the value 1 is equivalent to at least one of the values of the component in the vector.

This seems similar to showing that an element is a member of a set, but clearly it's not exactly the same since the vector's components are not guaranteed to be distinct, as is in the case of a set.  So I can't use the "member of" ($1\in X$) notation.  So is there any appropriate notation for what I'm trying to show?

Answer (score 3):

Given a vector $v=\langle v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_k\rangle$ then the statement that $1$ is at least one of the entries can be stated as $\exists i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ such that $v_i=1$.

That being said, I think it is still easier said in words.  It should be pointed out, though, that this is not a totally useful property in terms of linear algebra since the property of "having an entry equal to one" while true according to one basis can be false according to a different basis.

Answer (score 1):

Define $U_a$ as the union of the hyper planes $H_i(a)$ where $x_i=a$ $$U_a=\cup_{i=1}^{n}H_i(a)$$

Then you can say $X \in U_1$ for what you are looking for.

Unfortunately, I don’t know any pre-existing standard notation for this.